# Patrón Builder (Builder Pattern) mediante Interfaz Fluida (Fluent Interface) en PHP

Tags: php, patrones-de-diseño

Estoy intentando hacer el patrón Builder (Builder Pattern) en PHP, y estoy intentando hacerlo con interfaz fluida, pero mi problema es que no es igual como sería en Java.

Pongo un ejemplo sencillo para ilustrar la duda de como se haría el mismo patrón en PHP:

Tenemos la clase **Usuario** que representa un modelo de nuestra aplicación.

```
class Usuario{
    private $username;
    private $password;
    private $email;

    public function __construct($username, $password, $email) {
          $this->username = $username;
          $this->password = $password;
          $this->email = $email;
    }

    /*Getters y Setter de las variables*/
```

Tenemos una clase *Builder* (**UsuarioBuilder**) para crear objetos de la clase Usuario que tiene los métodos para construir el objeto:

```
class UsuarioBuilder {
    private $username = '';
    private $password = '';
    private $email = '';

    public function withUserName($username) {
          $this->username = $username;
          return $this;
    }

    public function withPassword($password) {
          $this->password= $password;
          return $this;
    }

    public function withEmail($email) {
          $this->email = $email;
          return $this;
    }

    public function build() {
          return new Usuario($this->username, $this->password, $this->email);
    }
}
```

Esa sería la clase que utilizo para tener el *Builder* y crear los objetos **Usuario** a partir de esa clase. Pero aquí es donde me da error y no sé como se haría.
Al intentar crear un objeto **Usuario** a través de la clase **UsuarioBuilder** me da un error:

```
$rodriUser = new UsuarioBuilder()
                  ->withUserName('Rodri')
                  ->withPassword('123456a')
                  ->withEmail('rodri@example.com')
                  ->build();
```

No me deja (como sería en Java) desde el constructor de la clase **UsuarioBuilder** llamar al resto de métodos y obtengo un error de sintaxis en la línea cuando llamo al primer método "->withUserName()". No puedo llamar métodos desde el constructor como en Java que si se puede.  ¿Cómo sería la forma correcta de implementar este patrón en PHP?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Encierra la operacion de inicializacion entre parentesis para que te retorne la instancia y asi puedas acceder a sus miembros:

```
$usuario = (new UsuarioBuilder())
                  ->withUserName('Rodri')
                  ->withPassword('123456a')
                  ->withEmail('rodri@example.com')
                  ->build();
```

Probablemente el error se deba a que esa sintaxis no sea reconocida por el interpreter de php.

Actualizacion:

Es bueno notar que esa sintaxis solo funciona desde [php 5.4.0](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php) y el nombre es **Acceso de miembros de clase en la instancia**

Comment: +1 Quizás mencionar que es compatible a partir de la version `5.4.0` [link doc](http://docs.php.net/manual/es/migration54.new-features.php)

Comment: Perfecto, me sirvió poniendo la inicialización entre paréntesis, muchas gracias. Pero ¿hacer eso tiene algún nombre o algún por qué?

Comment: A eso se le llama "Acceso a miembros de una instancia". Al parecer no la sintaxis no era soportada previamente.